# What is going on in ArcMap AddIn?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I have an ArcMap-addin which is working from ArcMap 10.2 until 10.8 but since an undefinite time in undefined circumstances there happen things that I can't explain. I'm searching for the cause while debugging and an *ILayer* object which is also an *IFeatureLayer* (its a Shape) sometimes is an *IFeatureLayer* and sometimes not.

The next curious thing is that in code the program run into the if-clause but in the watched variables of Visual-Studio is the complete contrast.

I have no idea whats there going on or if I have a massive problem in understanding the arcobjects com philosophy?

Has anyone seen something like this?
[image]

Comment: That looks strange indeed. The first thing I'd try is to remove the addin from ArcMap, then clean and rebuild the project. Another thought: Is `pLayer` a local variable, or could it be possible that it's modified elsewhere in your code?

Comment: pLayer is a local variable and there are no other threads or events. Maybe its because its a virtual pc where ArcMap and Visual Studio is running?

Comment: I have found 'is' to be inconsistent in some situations (such as for 'IWorkspaceFactory's). My experience with the watch variables also is pretty inconsistent. In those situations I tend towards 'as' and then check for null and also writing info to the debug output instead of using watch.

Comment: Sometimes ArcObjects is just a bit broken. Try deleting the ESRI folders in your local and roaming appdata folders and retrying the add-in. Also the relevant folder in ..\Documents\ArcGis\AddIns\Desktop10.X\<addin folder>. That has fixed a decent number of odd issues.